# Get posts from multiple post type

Tags: php, wp-query

I need to display posts from multiple post type with two queries so I found this answer:
[How to display posts from multiple post type in random order in wordpress?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152367/how-to-display-posts-from-multiple-post-type-in-random-order-in-wordpress)

But can't use it to get post data like post content or post title, The author of the answer write I must set up by setup_postdata but I can't understand.

Any help, please?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you really need two separate queries? Because with `WP_Query` and `get_posts` you can already query multiple post_types. In the query args you can add a array like: `'post_type'  => array('post', 'product' )`.

Comment: @LWS-Mo Yes i think i must use two separate queries because i want to set custom meta value and term for each one so i think i must use two separate queries, right? I'm waiting you i really need your help for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to query posts from multiple post types, but also with different query-arguments like custom field, tax_query or categories.

As you did not post what you tried, have already or want to have, please try something like this:

We are using 3 queries to set everything up. You can add different arguments to each query.

Get `post ID´s` from our first post type, `product`:

```
$first_post_ids = get_posts( array(
    'fields'         => 'ids', // only return post ID´s
    'posts_per_page' => '5',
    'post_type'      => array('product'),
));
```

Get `post ID´s` from our second post type, `post`:

```
$second_post_ids = get_posts( array(
    'fields'         => 'ids', // only return post ID´s
    'posts_per_page' => '5',
    'post_type'      => array('post'),
));
```

Merge our two queries into one:

```
$merged_post_ids = array_merge( $first_post_ids, $second_post_ids);
```

Build the third query:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'any', // any post type
    'post__in'  => $merged_post_ids, // our merged queries
) );
```

The loop:

```
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();

        //look at $post here !!
        //Example: $post->post_type;
        //this return the type of each post so you can do checks and stuff

        //for example show title and content
        the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>' );
        the_content();

    endwhile;

    // reset after query
    wp_reset_query();

else :
    echo 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.';
endif;
```

---

**Update: Check if array_merge is not null to prevent any types showing**

`array_merge` is used to merge 2 arrays, like the name suggests.

So for example, if `$first_post_ids` is a `string`, than it will not work. Thats why we use `'fields' => 'ids',` in our queries.
Because as the Codex says:

> 'ids' - Return an array of post IDs.

And even if one of these two queries is empty (i.e. we have no posts), `array_merge` will still work.

But yes, we can check `array_merge`:

```
//... first two queries

$merged_post_ids = array_merge( $first_post_ids, $second_post_ids );

//check if the array_merge exists/not null
if ( $merged_post_ids ) {

    $wp_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'any', // any post type
        'post__in'  => $merged_post_ids, // our merged queries
    ) );

    //... your query code here

}//END if $merged_post_ids
```

You can also expand it with an `else` statement to let another query run.

Comment: There's a small bug in your code, id no posts found in the post type your code will get any anther post type like pages and attachments so I try to change 'post_type' => 'any', to 'post_type' => array('product', 'post'), but it's not working. Any solution?

Comment: If we make something to check if array_merge is not empty this will solve the problem? if yes please update your answer.

Comment: @Trello yes, we can check `array_merge`. I just updated my answer with some details.

Comment: Thank you again you are a good person yea it's working with me but be known that to make it working we must check if array merge not empty from $wp_query = new WP_Query( array( to endif; because if we don't make this some pages also will appear as a post, I hope you understand me :)

Comment: @Trello sorry I dont fully understand what you mean :) We must first check `$merged_post_ids`. If it is not null, than we can use it in our third query. So our third query is _inside the if check_, because if `array_merge` is null we cannot use the third query.(So the whole `$wp_query->have_posts()` section is inside the if function)  If you want to check before you merge the two arrays, you can maybe use (if) `is_array`.

Comment: Yes and now I understand you, but now we don't need to use if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : because if ( $merged_post_ids ) { will already do this so we can add else for if merged_post_ids and print no posts exists right?